# rake db:migrate UNEXPECTED error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello pls help with an unexpected error when I run my rails app. 
**rake db:migrate**
then there is an error

```
CreateTodoItems: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:todo_items)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `reference' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007f9d9c981ed0>/Users/chenziwang/odot/db/migrate/20150421184553_create_todo_items.rb:4:in `block in change'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:202:in `create_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/Users/chenziwang/odot/db/migrate/20150421184553_create_todo_items.rb:3:in `change'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my migrate files are:

```
class CreateTodoLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :todo_lists do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Another file is

```
class CreateTodoItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :todo_items do |t|
      t.reference :todo_list
      t.string :content

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe post your migration file.

Comment: class CreateTodoLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :todo_lists do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

Comment: class CreateTodoItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :todo_items do |t|
      t.reference :todo_list
      t.string :content

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 4):

In your second migration you've got `t.reference :todo_list`, that's wrong. You should have `t.references :todo_list`. Plural.

Comment: thank you so MUCH! it works trying to figure it out the whole afternoon.this save my Friday!

Comment: No problem at all. :)

Comment: @ChenziWang since CD-RUM's answer helped solve your issue, please consider accepting it. You'll also get 2 reputation for doing so! :)